# How can I create an instance of one model as soon as an instance of a different model is created?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two linked models:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Users of my site register and create an account first (MyUser), should be able to view their not-yet-created/blank profile (Profile), and then have the option of editing/saving their blank profile from within the profile_detail page.
My ProfileDetailView:

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'profile/profile_detail.html'
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_profile)
        return obj
```

They cannot access their own profile page after registration due to their profile instance not having been created. To allow them to go to their profile and view the blank profile, then update their ProfileUpdateForm from there, I've attempted signaling:

```
def user_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
  if not instance.profile.exists():
     Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

as well as

```
def user_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):  
  Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

The first of the two returns `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: MyUser has no profile.`
The second works, but Django docs do not recommend using get_or_create there.

What is a better way to achieve the desired result?
Also, is a `class ProfileCreateView(CreateView):` even necessary in this case when I have

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
    template_name = 'profile/profile_edit.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_profile)
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That signal has a `created` argument; you can check that, because you know that a newly-created User needs a Profile.

```
def user_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
  if created:
     Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```